# Crash when using deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded with Realm in Swift

Tags: swift, realm

I'm doing the following inside of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(
  schemaVersion: 0,
  deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: true
)
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

let realm = try! Realm()
```

Basically, while developing, I don't want to worry about migrations and just want to clear the database whenever the schema changes. My understanding is that's exactly what `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded` is for.

The problem is that sometimes it crashes while trying to initialize Realm with the following **error**:

> fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=5 "Directory at path '/Users/rock/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D626848E-14D5-47AC-8FFB-9B67D024DEF1/data/Containers/Data/Application/6F71103C-9E10-4131-BED4-D96445FABA52/Documents/default.realm' does not exist."

The default.realm file is getting removed, presumably because of `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded`, but then isn't getting recreated (as I'd expect) when initializing Realm with that last line.

Interestingly, if I manually delete `default.realm.lock` and then restart the app, it'll work.

Am I doing this wrong? Could this be a bug? (I'm using Realm Swift 2.4.1)

Comment: Hmm, I just tried this out in the Realm demo apps and it worked fine. It should 'just work' without any extra effort, so if you're experiencing a reliable crash, it might actually be some kind of edge case bug you've stumbled upon. Please file a bug report at https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues and try and include as much of the code from your app as you can.

Comment: Yeah it's interesting that it's inconsistent — I don't yet have a reliable repro. Also I have a feeling it might only be an issue in the simulator, because it hasn't happened on the device yet.

I'll file a bug report with as much info as I can — thanks!

Comment: This may have been your problem: I ran into this issue when I had the Realm Browser open showing the then-deleted database at the same time.

Comment: +1 @teacup - I also ran into this when the Realm Browser was open. Just closed it and everything works fine. Why don't you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 34):

I just came across the same problem and the solution in my case was to turn off the Realm Browser if you have it open.

Cheers!

Comment: This does it. Incredibly inconvenient.

Comment: Lol still an issue in almost 2020. Thanks! I just was worried that some thing may happen when my customer will install a new update.

Comment: Totally crazy, Im facing the same issue over and over again, then after couple of hours I come back to this answer.

Comment: Thanks Michael, saved me a lot of hunting around

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that turning off encryption when setting up the Realm will allow you to have the Realm Browser open at the same time.